# Add a binding from a prompt and get selected range with Office.js API

Tags: excel, office-js

I want to get the values of a range binding from a prompt.
To implement this I follow the spec: [Add a binding from a prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/bind-to-regions-in-a-document-or-spreadsheet#add-a-binding-from-a-prompt)

It's working only when I select one cell but it give me the following error when I select more than one cell:

[image]

I reproduce this in the Script Lab tool and I have export a gist. The gist is available on:
[Get data binding from a prompt.EXCEL.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Nassim33/4131bf1e73ca92663481a6e828035eef#file-get-data-binding-from-a-prompt-excel-yaml)

For testing,

1. click on "Set binding on data" button (to create a binding on the cells to get their values)
2. click on "Get data" button  (to get the values for the binding)
3. the problem occured

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can reproduce. Please raise this as an issue on the office-js repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Comment: I have created the following issue on the office-js repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1653

Answer (score 0):

We provided 2 binding APIs

- Common Binding API, which used for Excel/Word/Powerpoint, etc.
- Another one is for excel specific, we call them Rich API.

As you are working on Excel Project, so we suggest that you could use our rich API `workbook.bindings` to add a binding to multiple cells.

```
const newBinding = context.workbook.bindings.add("A1:A100","Range","cc1c.onDataChangedBinding:"+"A1:A100");
```

Because Common binding API (document.bindings) does not support add binding to multiple cells which is by design.